# No audio /// WebRTC + Asterisk + jsSIP in Local Network

Tags: audio, webrtc, asterisk, rtp, jssip

I'd appreciate a lot your help with this issue. I'm running a very basic script of JS with a jsSIP User Agent that uses a local Asterisk server for making voice calls. Everything is on a private network, and I don't get any warnings or errors from the Asterisk CLI, but when I make a call to a legacy SIP phone or a test extension, **there is no audio on any side although there is ringing, calls can be answered and they never drop.** My Asterisk 12 was compiled with SRTP and pjproject.

I read at the Asterisk WebRTC Wiki (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support) this: *"Starting with Asterisk 12 you need to have pjproject libraries installed, otherwise you most likely won't have audio in your WebRTC calls and no warning whatsoever!"*
I properly installed it and selected it for the Asterisk compilation, but I wonder wether I did it wrong, and how can I check it ...

**These are my Asterisk files:**

```
http.conf
[general]
enabled=yes;
bindaddr=0.0.0.0;
bindport=8088;
prefix=asterisk;
tlsenable=yes;
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089;
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem; 
tlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem;

rtp.conf
[general]
rtpstart=10000;
rtpend=20000;
icesupport=true;
stunaddr=stun.l.google.com:19302;

sip.conf
[general]
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm

[1000]  ;legacy softphone (zoiper)
secret=******
type=friend 
host=dynamic    
dtmfmode=rfc2833    
disallow=all    
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
context=myContext

[1001]  ;jsSIP User Agent
type=friend
username=1001
host=dynamic
secret=******
encryption=yes
avpf=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
transport=udp,ws
force_avp=yes 
dtlsenable=yes 
dtlsverify=no
disallow=all
allow=ilbc
allow=g729
allow=gsm
allow=g723
allow=ulaw
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem 
dtlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem 
dtlssetup=actpass 
context=myContext
```

**This is my JS script with my jsSIP client:**

```
var ua = null;
var session = null;
var myMultimedia = document.getElementById('myMultimedia');
var theirMultimedia = document.getElementById('theirMultimedia');
var local_stream = null;
var remote_stream = null;

function registerUA() {

    var configuration = {
        uri: "sip:1001@192.168.0.4",
        password: ******,
        ws_servers: "ws://192.168.0.4:8088/asterisk/ws",
        display_name: "UA WebRTC",
        authorization_user: null,
        register: null,
        register_expires: null,
        no_answer_timeout: null,
        trace_sip: true,
        stun_servers: null,
        turn_servers: null,
        use_preloaded_route: null,
        connection_recovery_min_interval: null,
        connection_recovery_max_interval: null,
        hack_via_tcp: null,
        hack_ip_in_contact: true
    };
    ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);
    ua.start();
}

function callAsterisk() {

    var numTel = document.getElementById('numTel').value;
    console.log(numTel);

    var eventH = {
        'progress': function (e) { },
        'failed': function (e) { },
        'ended': function (e) { },
        'confirmed': function (e) {
            local_stream = session.connection.getLocalStreams()[0]; 
 console.log(local_stream); //If i print this variable I do get a media stream
            myMultimedia = JsSIP.rtcninja.attachMediaStream(myMultimedia, local_stream); 
        },
        'addstream': function (e) {
            remote_stream = e.stream; 
console.log(remote_stream); //If i print this variable I do get a media stream
 theirMultimedia = JsSIP.rtcninja.attachMediaStream(theirMultimedia, remote_stream); 
        }
    };

    var options = {
        'eventHandlers': eventH,
        'mediaConstraints': {
            'audio': true,
            'video': false
        }
    };
    session = ua.call('sip:' + numTel + '@192.168.0.4', options);
}
```

Here I leave the debugging of jsSIP showing the SIP messages related to the subscribing of my UA and the dialing to the test extension 200 ('hello-world' recording):

**1. Subscribing:**

```
JsSIP:UA configuration parameters after validation: +0ms
JsSIP:UA - via_host: "192.0.2.177" +8ms
JsSIP:UA - password: NOT SHOWN +7ms
JsSIP:UA - register_expires: 600 +6ms
JsSIP:UA - register: true +5ms
JsSIP:UA - registrar_server: sip:192.168.0.4 +6ms
JsSIP:UA - ws_server_max_reconnection: 3 +5ms
JsSIP:UA - ws_server_reconnection_timeout: 4 +5ms
JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_min_interval: 2 +5ms
JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_max_interval: 30 +6ms
JsSIP:UA - use_preloaded_route: false +8ms
JsSIP:UA - no_answer_timeout: 60000 +6ms
JsSIP:UA - session_timers: true +5ms
JsSIP:UA - hack_via_tcp: false +4ms
JsSIP:UA - hack_via_ws: false +5ms
JsSIP:UA - hack_ip_in_contact: true +5ms
JsSIP:UA - node_websocket_options: {} +5ms
JsSIP:UA - uri: sip:1001@192.168.0.4 +6ms
JsSIP:UA - ws_servers: [{"ws_uri":"ws://192.168.0.4:8088/asterisk/ws","sip_uri":"<sip:192.168.0.4:8088;transport=ws;lr>","weight":0,"status":0,"scheme":"WS"}] +5ms
JsSIP:UA - display_name: "UA WebRTC" +6ms
JsSIP:UA - instance_id: "b1a09033-7533-47a8-a039-1a6760b2af84" +5ms
JsSIP:UA - jssip_id: "6gejr" +5ms
JsSIP:UA - hostport_params: "192.168.0.4" +4ms
JsSIP:UA - authorization_user: "1001" +5ms
JsSIP:UA start() +6ms
JsSIP:Transport connecting to WebSocket ws://192.168.0.4:8088/asterisk/ws +6ms
JsSIP:Transport WebSocket ws://192.168.0.4:8088/asterisk/ws connected +150ms
JsSIP:Transport
sending WebSocket message:

REGISTER sip:192.168.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK9352120
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=f8m06houfb
Call-ID: liamoji649fhds9jtdajfi
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:b1a09033-7533-47a8-a039-1a6760b2af84>";expires=600
Expires: 600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER
Supported: path,gruu,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.4
Content-Length: 0

+15ms
jssip-0.7.4.js (line 22459)
JsSIP:Transport
received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK9352120;received=192.168.0.4
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=f8m06houfb
To: <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2235a73d
Call-ID: liamoji649fhds9jtdajfi
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="0f6c6c26"
Content-Length: 0


+30ms
jssip-0.7.4.js (line 22459)
JsSIP:Transport
sending WebSocket message:

REGISTER sip:192.168.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK1900716
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=f8m06houfb
Call-ID: liamoji649fhds9jtdajfi
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1001", realm="asterisk", nonce="0f6c6c26", uri="sip:192.168.0.4", response="bed4984f5fc3c21f3854dccdb30a74b2"
Contact: <sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:b1a09033-7533-47a8-a039-1a6760b2af84>";expires=600
Expires: 600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER
Supported: path,gruu,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.4
Content-Length: 0

+32ms
jssip-0.7.4.js (line 22459)
JsSIP:Transport
received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK1900716;received=192.168.0.4
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=f8m06houfb
To: <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2235a73d
Call-ID: liamoji649fhds9jtdajfi
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

Supported: replaces, timer
Expires: 600
Contact: <sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws>;expires=600
Date: Mon, 24 Aug 2015 14:15:52 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**2. Making a call to extension 200 (hello-world):**

```
JsSIP:UA call() +3m
JsSIP:RTCSession new +10ms
JsSIP:RTCSession connect() +10ms
JsSIP:RTCSession newRTCSession +200ms
JsSIP:RTCSession session connecting +1s
JsSIP:RTCSession createLocalDescription() +8ms
JsSIP:Transport 
sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:200@192.168.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK2696832
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9260 INVITE
Contact: <sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws;ob>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Session-Expires: 90
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER
Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.4
Content-Length: 936

v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-40.0 4294967295 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 2F:5D:E3:B3:9B:9C:8E:00:AF:81:CC:E8:39:CA:05:CF:40:D1:66:11:91:3A:F1:A2:6D:78:D5:51:5F:22:96:AC
a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 35823 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
c=IN IP4 192.168.0.4
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.0.4 35823 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.0.4 35135 typ host
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ice-pwd:516e745ffd8bf121177f0b7680506018
a=ice-ufrag:37f2205c
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{aa42a325-b228-4ff3-b52f-de1f1288836e} {7b2300a8-f4ea-4b74-bbfa-ac5c4835b3c8}
a=rtcp:35135 IN IP4 192.168.0.4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:1479786588 cname:{0dbce354-bdf6-4ee7-acb0-e4f12c501e04}

 +70ms
JsSIP:Transport 
received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK2696832;received=192.168.0.4
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as34ac1926
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9260 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="3d67a76d"
Content-Length: 0

 +43ms
JsSIP:Transport 
sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:200@192.168.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK2696832
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as34ac1926
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9260 ACK
Content-Length: 0

 +40ms
JsSIP:Transport 
sending WebSocket message:

INVITE sip:200@192.168.0.4 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK3632996
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9261 INVITE
Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="1001", realm="asterisk", nonce="3d67a76d", uri="sip:200@192.168.0.4", response="abff34d15fffc9b5baaadeab85d770c9"
Contact: <sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws;ob>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Session-Expires: 90
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER
Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.4
Content-Length: 936

v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-40.0 4294967295 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 2F:5D:E3:B3:9B:9C:8E:00:AF:81:CC:E8:39:CA:05:CF:40:D1:66:11:91:3A:F1:A2:6D:78:D5:51:5F:22:96:AC
a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 35823 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
c=IN IP4 192.168.0.4
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.0.4 35823 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.0.4 35135 typ host
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ice-pwd:516e745ffd8bf121177f0b7680506018
a=ice-ufrag:37f2205c
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{aa42a325-b228-4ff3-b52f-de1f1288836e} {7b2300a8-f4ea-4b74-bbfa-ac5c4835b3c8}
a=rtcp:35135 IN IP4 192.168.0.4
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:1479786588 cname:{0dbce354-bdf6-4ee7-acb0-e4f12c501e04}

 +18ms
JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer D expired for transaction z9hG4bK2696832 +44ms
JsSIP:Transport 
received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK3632996;received=192.168.0.4
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9261 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Session-Expires: 90;refresher=uas
Contact: <sip:200@192.168.0.4:5060;transport=WS>
Content-Length: 0

 +116ms
JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +31ms
JsSIP:Transport 
received WebSocket text message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK3632996;received=192.168.0.4
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2a14b282
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9261 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Session-Expires: 90;refresher=uas
Contact: <sip:200@192.168.0.4:5060;transport=WS>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Require: timer
Content-Length: 774

v=0
o=root 1590611571 1590611571 IN IP4 192.168.0.4
s=Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
c=IN IP4 192.168.0.4
t=0 0
m=audio 19864 RTP/SAVPF 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=ptime:20
a=maxptime:150
a=ice-ufrag:00b9259c164316017df96bd7099a0b59
a=ice-pwd:3eac7a773d965d021529752477b9278e
a=candidate:Hc0a80004 1 UDP 2130706431 192.168.0.4 19864 typ host
a=candidate:Sbdd9418e 1 UDP 1694498815 189.217.65.142 35710 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.4 rport 19864
a=candidate:Hc0a80004 2 UDP 2130706430 192.168.0.4 19865 typ host
a=candidate:Sbdd9418e 2 UDP 1694498814 189.217.65.142 46555 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.4 rport 19865
a=connection:new
a=setup:active
a=fingerprint:SHA-256 E2:B9:77:44:04:96:8D:D9:EA:67:B9:E0:6E:93:49:08:5B:33:53:7D:DD:51:5A:1B:0F:7D:45:CA:BD:F9:CE:BA
a=sendrecv

 +8ms
JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +21ms
JsSIP:Dialog new UAC dialog created with status CONFIRMED +9ms
JsSIP:RTCSession session accepted +29ms
JsSIP:RTCSession sendRequest() +10ms
JsSIP:RTCSession:Request new | ACK +11ms
JsSIP:Transport 
sending WebSocket message:

ACK sip:200@192.168.0.4:5060;transport=ws SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.0.2.177;branch=z9hG4bK5815096
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2a14b282
From: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 9261 ACK
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.4
Content-Length: 0

 +18ms
JsSIP:RTCSession session confirmed +11ms
 LocalMediaStream { id="{aa42a325-b228-4ff3-b52f-de1f1288836e}",  currentTime=0.300375,  stop=stop(),  more...}//printing of local stream
miScript.js (line 69)
CALL CONFIRMED
miScript.js (line 70)
element is null
jssip-0.7.4.js (line 22924)
 MediaStream { id="{38caf558-e986-4c52-b9cd-4abe5384051e}",  currentTime=0.0309375,  getAudioTracks=getAudioTracks(),  more...}
//printing of remote stream
miScript.js (line 77)
REMOTE STREAM RECEIVED
miScript.js (line 78)
TypeError: element is null
jssip-0.7.4.js (line 22924, col 17)
JsSIP:Transport 
received WebSocket text message:

BYE sip:grd0bbtt@192.0.2.177;transport=ws;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.4:5060;branch=z9hG4bK4a805194
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2a14b282
To: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 12.8.2
Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:192.168.0.4", nonce="3d67a76d", response="4ff114fe1b3b95781c646407da538133"
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
Content-Length: 0

 +2s
JsSIP:RTCSession receiveRequest() +22ms
JsSIP:Transport 
sending WebSocket message:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.0.4:5060;branch=z9hG4bK4a805194
To: "UA WebRTC" <sip:1001@192.168.0.4>;tag=9q1k7ijiab
From: <sip:200@192.168.0.4>;tag=as2a14b282
Call-ID: 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv8
CSeq: 102 BYE
Supported: outbound
Content-Length: 0

 +12ms
JsSIP:RTCSession session ended +12ms
JsSIP:RTCSession close() +8ms
JsSIP:RTCSession close() | closing local MediaStream +12ms
JsSIP:Dialog dialog 6gejrmupvj5asi2fdhv89q1k7ijiabas2a14b282 deleted +11ms
JsSIP:NonInviteServerTransaction Timer J expired for transaction z9hG4bK4a805194 +29ms
TypeError: e.data is undefined
miScript.js (line 65, col 12)
```

**Finally, this is what the Asterisk CLI says:
When I subscribe:**

```
== WebSocket connection from '192.168.0.4:55061' for protocol 'sip' accepted using version '13'
    -- Registered SIP '1001' at 192.168.0.4:55061
```

**When I call:**

```
 == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [200@myContext:1] Answer("SIP/1001-00000005", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [200@myContext:2] Playback("SIP/1001-00000005", "hello-world") in new stack
Sent RTP packet to      192.168.0.4:51805 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 019963, ts 000160, len 000160)
    -- <SIP/1001-00000005> Playing 'hello-world.gsm' (language 'en')
Sent RTP packet to      192.168.0.4:51805 (via ICE) (type 00, seq 019964, ts 000320, len 000160)
```

Did I miss anything obvious? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete Asterisk log including sip log.

Comment: @spicyramen Thank u for the reply! I was starting to think that my question was about to be forever ignored .... These are my logs from asterisk: 1. SIP messages when registering my jsSIP client: http://pastebin.com/GNZETtQb. 2. SIP messages when making a call to a extension that invokes a "hello world" recording: http://pastebin.com/0PxjLwBb.

Comment: But furthermore, I wonder wether you can help me understand about the IP address everything should be linked to. I'm doing my tests on a local environment but I saw that my RTP flows are redirected to my eth address. I ended up using my public IP for the http server and the DTLS certificates. Now I see that my RTP flows are redirected there but still any audio nor warning. Can I use a local address? If I link the http server to one of those it doesn't work since it's not configurated to any eth. This is my conf: http.conf (http://pastebin.com/ZwJWiiwf) sip.conf(http://pastebin.com/kWwXpi4V)

Comment: Can you not edit the ip addresses in log. Or if you going to edit it not mask it to x.x.x use a meaningful value. Will take a look in detail once close to my computer

Comment: Before that, I would like to ask you which would be the steps for making a local configuration. I tried using localhost for the http.conf file, as well as the DTLS certificate. However, I still get no audio. Which should be the ip addresses I should use for a local usage? I'm kinda desperated here haha

Comment: Which browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm using the most recent version of Mozilla Firefox. It seems that with Chrome neither jsSIP nor sipML5 trigger the bubble asking permission for mic access ....